# Need to send file data from angular 7 application to Javascript Application

Tags: javascript, angular7

I am trying to create the Preview of the selected file as Flipbook.
I am having angular 7 application where I am uploading image and I have to create flipbook view for the selected file for that I found one Javascript Flipbook project.

But not understanding the in tegration of both project as I am not knowing Javascript too much.

I thought to create one post call from angular 7 project consist of file data as request parameter and access that url through Javascript project using `XMLHttpRequest`.
but not sure about implementation. 
Can anyone help me to get integration of both project?